# How to mock a method of a class instance?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have code like this:

a.py

```
from app.cache import Cache 
my_cache = Cache(cache_prefix='xxxxx')
```

b.py

```
from a import my_cache
class MyApp:
     def run_app():
         my_cache.get(1,2)
```

test_b.py

```
from mock import Mock, patch
import b
mock_my_cache_get= Mock(b.my_cache.get)

class MyTests():
     @patch('b.my_cache.get', mock_my_cache_get)
     def test_cache(self):
          b.MyApp().run_app()
          mock_my_cache_get.assert_called_with(1,2)
```

As you can see above, I am trying to write a unit test where I mock the get method of the class instance of Cache. However, when I try to assert that this mocked method is called with the specified arguments, I get an error saying that call is not found. Which, as iis obvious that is is.

Comment: Nowhere in your code have you called `MyApp.run_app`, which is what would call `my_cache.get`. Show us a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: What does **Which, as iis obvious that is is** mean? Please help me to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can leave unchanged files `a.py` and `b.py`, but you have to change your `test_b.py` as following:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import b         # <--------------- add the import

mock_my_cache_get = Mock(b.my_cache.get)

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('b.my_cache.get', mock_my_cache_get)
    def test_cache(self):
        b.MyApp().run_app()    # <--- add the call to the method under test
        mock_my_cache_get.assert_called_with(1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

- In the test you have to call the `run_app()` method.
- Furthermore you have to add the `import b` instruction.

---

**EDIT**
I have replicated your code in my system and the structure of my folder is:

```
question_76708763
 |--app
 |   |-cache.py
 |--a.py
 |--b.py
 |--test_b.py
```

Following I report how I have executed the test in my system and the output of the execution:

```
> cd /path/to/question_76708763

> python test_b.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

It is strange what happens in your system.

Comment: I have updated my example to include the call. I missed it when I posted. Still gives me the error

Comment: @user2611836 I have updated my answer. Please report the exact error message in your question.

Comment: @user2611836 your class MyTest inherits from unittest.TestCase?